# Google Authenticator show title in app entry

Tags: php, google-authenticator

I have successfully created a page that uses 2 step auth, which includes google authenticator.  When i create the user, and scan the barcode on my phone.  I correctly see the username as well as the 6 digit auth code.  My customer suggests that I can put a title or name in this area as well, so he knows which auth entry goes to what server.  Is this possible, and if so, where can i find the documentation?

I am using ga4php.php

Answer (score 2):

The title or name of your app can be included by filling out the 'issuer' parameter of the QR code.
See https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format